# Any plugin to make a 3 levels menu?

Tags: menus, css

I'm looking for a plugin (even if need some customization) to do something like this:

[image]

It's possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the menu editor, you can add several levels already:
[image]
Where the different levels appear and how is a question of your theme/style sheet, so it's not a plugin issue.